# Scheduling a Powershell process does not yield the same results as when I run it manually

Tags: powershell

I wrote a small PowerShell script that I am using to query the Server Log, clean the return values and use some of the results to perform some server maintenance.  However, when I schedule the save to file piece is not writing the whole content to the file and it is getting truncated, just like what I ma posting below, exactly.  As you can observe, the end of the file is truncated with three dots added to replace the missing values:

```
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 2...
```

However, if I run the code manually with Local Admin access, the content gets saved to the local file like this, exactly:

```
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 112.103.198.2]
```

Why is this the case when I schedule the process or PS file to run under a schedule.  BTW, I tried to run it under the SYSTEM context with full or highest privileges and even used the same Admin account that I use to run it manually to schedule and still do nt get the full content of the event that I save.

This is creating an issue and I am not able to use the content to process the IP.

Here is the PS code that I am using to query and save the content to file:

```
    $SQL = 'C:\SQL.txt'

    Remove-Item $SQL -ErrorAction Ignore

    Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 18456} | 
    Select-Object -Property Message | Out-File $SQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with `out-file` because it has a default character limit of 80 per line.
You can change it with `-width` property and give a value of say 200. However `set-content` doesn't have these limits set in. So it might be a more suitable option.

All that being said, I am not sure why it does it one way when ran manually vs another when the system runs it.

[Out-file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7) defaults to unicode when writing files

[set-file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7) defaults to ascii when writing files